# Why does null-propagation not work for events?

Tags: c#

Background: [C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

```
using System;

internal sealed class Program
{
    private sealed class Inner
    {
        internal int Value { get; } = 42;
        internal void DoSomething(int value) { }
        internal event EventHandler Event;
    }

    private sealed class Outer
    {
        internal Inner Inner { get; } = new Inner();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Outer outer = null;

        // Works as expected (does not call Inner and Value, val is null)
        int? val = outer?.Inner.Value;

        // Works as expected (does not call Inner and DoSomething)
        outer?.Inner.DoSomething(42);

        // CS0070: The event 'Program.Inner.Event' can only appear on the left hand
        // side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Program.Inner')
        outer?.Inner.Event += (s, e) => { };
    }
}
```

Since the `+=` operator is just syntactic sugar for calling the add method of the event, I would have expected that the last line compiles just like the call to `DoSomething()` (and that it doesn't do anything at runtime).

Comment: What would you expect to happen if this was allowed and `outer` was null?

Comment: @DavidG See the remark in parenthesis, it should do nothing, just like the call to DoSomething()

Comment: But you will also notice that you can't do `outer?.Inner.Value = 42;`

Comment: The operator can only be used for "getting" things, not "setting" things. When you call a method, you are "getting" the method and doing something with it (invoking it). You are effectively trying to get and set a property.

Answer (score 5):

The `+=` operator is indeed syntactic sugar for a method call, but it is an operator, not a method call.

The code on the left hand side of the `+=` operator is:

```
outer?.Inner.Event
```

Code on the left hand side of that operator needs to evaluate to something that can be assigned to and has a `+` operator defined on it (e.g. a variable of delegate type), or an event.

This code cannot evaluate to an event if `outer == null`, which is why it is illegal.